# Entity Framework Core duplicando item em tabela relacionada

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, entity-framework-core

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação C# Windows Forms (.NET 6.0), acessando dados no MySQL usando o EF Core 7. Neste projeto tenho uma tabela MASTER chamada FORMAPAGTOS, conforme a classe/model abaixo:

```
public class FormaPagto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Descricao { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ParcelasModel>? Parcelas { get; set; }
}
```

Ela tem a tabela DETALHE chamada PAGTOPARCELAS conforme a classe/model abaixo:

```
public class ParcelasModel
{
    public int IdFormaPagto { get; set; }
    public int IdParcela { get; set; }
    public int Prazo { get; set; }
    public int Percentual { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdFormaPagto")]
    public FormaPagto? FormaPagto { get; set; }
}
```

Esta tabela, PAGTOPARCELAS, tem a PRIMARY KEY composta pelos campos **IdFormaPagto** e **IdParcela**, configurada por FLUENT API, conforme o DBContext abaixo:

```
public class ContextDB : DbContext
{
    public ContextDB(DbContextOptions<ContextDB> options) : base(options) {}

    public DbSet<FormaPagto> FormaPagtos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ParcelasModel> PagtoParcelas { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string cn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localMySQL"].ConnectionString;
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(cn, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(cn));
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ParcelasModel>()
                    .HasKey(s => new { s.IdFormaPagto, s.IdParcela });
    }
}
```

Quando tento salvar dados na tabela DETALHE recebo o erro **Duplicate entry '3' for key 'formapagtos.PRIMARY'** como se estivesse tentando incluir um novo registro na tabela MASTER com um Id que já existe, conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Reproduzindo a inserção de dados via comando no MySQL Workbench o erro não acontece:

`` INSERT INTO `wtdbnfe`.`pagtoparcelas` (`IdParcela`,`IdFormaPagto`,`Prazo`,`Percentual`) VALUES (1,3,28,34), (2,3,35,33), (3,3,45,33); ``

A tabela DETALHE é carregada como um ICOLLECTION:

```
    public async Task<FormaPagto?> Get(int id)
    {
        FormaPagto? result = await _db.FormaPagtos
                                   .Include(p => p.Parcelas)
                                   .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

        return result;
    }
```

Ao atualizar os dados do registro de Id: 3 é feita a remoção de todos os itens que tem esse Id da tabela DETALHE, em seguida é feita a inserção dos itens atualizados que foram digitados/editados em um DataGridView:

```
    public async Task<List<ParcelasModel>> GetAll(int idForma)
    {
        return await _db.PagtoParcelas.AsNoTracking()
                                      .Where(f=>f.IdFormaPagto == idForma)
                                      .ToListAsync();
    }
    public async Task DeleteAll(int idForma)
    {
        List<ParcelasModel> models = await GetAll(idForma);

        if (models.Any())
        {
            _db.PagtoParcelas.RemoveRange(models);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
    public async Task Create(ParcelasModel model)
    {
        _db.PagtoParcelas.Add(model);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    public async Task AddList(List<ParcelasModel> models)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in models)
            {
                await Create(item);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : ex.Message;
            MsgBox.Show(msg, "Salvando Parcelas", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

[image: Tela digitação FORMAS DE PAGAMENTO]

O que me parece é que o EF está tentando criar um novo registro na tabela MASTER para cada item adicionado na tabela DETALHE, com este cenário, fica a minha dúvida:

**Porque ao atualizar uma tabela DETALHE o EF tenta adicionar um novo registro a tabela MASTER?**

Comment: Talvez seja a falta de `Detach` do modelo no momento da criação!

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi da seguinte maneira:

Deixei essa forma de carregar os dados relacionados de lado .Include...

```
    public async Task<FormaPagto?> Get(int id)
    {
        FormaPagto? result = await _db.FormaPagtos
                                   .Include(p => p.Parcelas)
                                   .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

        return result;
    }
```

Agora eu busco a lista de itens relacionados (DETALHES) de forma independente, dessa forma o EF não rastreia a entidade MASTER, evitando esse comportamento bizarro.

```
    public async Task<List<ParcelasModel>> GetAll(int idForma)
    {
        return await _db.PagtoParcelas.Where(f=>f.IdFormaPagto == idForma)
                                      .ToListAsync();
    }
```

**Agradeço aos que tentaram ajudar de alguma forma.**

Ninguém veio ao mundo dotado de conhecimento pleno, todos nós temos dúvidas, o que hoje é complicado para alguém um dia já pode ter sido a sua dificuldade!

Answer (score -1):

Caso a sua entidade MASTER esteja sendo puxada quando você realiza um select na DETAILS, é possível que só um AsTracking na entidade MASTER faça com que esse problema pare de ocorrer. Pelo que tenho entendido, o EF tentará inserir tudo aquilo que a sua entidade principal estiver como referência.

Comment: Exatamente isso que estava ocorrendo!  Eu estava usando o `.Include(x => x.Detalhes)`  para buscar a entidade MASTER e já trazer todos os seus detalhes. Isso funciona bem para dados que serão só visualizados, pelo menos foi isso que ficou claro.
Obrigado pela ajuda @OtakuEmo !